# Testing functions of AngularFireAuth with jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, testing, jasmine

how are you? 
it's my first time with jasmine, and I'm lost.
I just want to test my method of AngularFireAuth.

I have this function in my service:

```js
emailPasswordLoginAsPromise(login) {

    return new Promise((resolveEPL, rejectEPL) => {

      this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(login.email, login.password)
        .then(credential => {
          resolveEPL(credential.user);
        }).catch(e => {
          console.error('emailPasswordLogin', e);
          rejectEPL(e);
        });
    });
  }
```

and I want to test in jasmine, and I have this in my Spec.js:

I know the basic of mocks, but I don't know how to apply this in my test, can anyone help me please? I tried to found some examples, but I got very confused.

```js
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

fdescribe('AuthService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [ 
        AuthService, AngularFireAuth, AngularFirestore 
      ]
    });
  });


  it('login correct', inject([AuthService], (service: AuthService) => {

    spyOn(service,'emailPasswordLoginAsPromise').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());

    let login = {
      email: 'email@gmail.com',
      password: 'correctpassword'
    }
      expect(service.emailPasswordLoginAsPromise(login)).toEqual(jasmine.any(Promise));
  }));

  it('login incorret', inject([AuthService], (service: AuthService) => {

    spyOn(service,'emailPasswordLoginAsPromise').and.returnValue(Promise.reject());

    let login = {
      email: 'email@gmail.com',
      password: 'wrongpassword'
    }
      expect(service.emailPasswordLoginAsPromise(login)).toEqual(jasmine.any(Promise));
  }));

});
```